# Postgresql revert back database value

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, delete, rollback

I have postgresql database.
My table name is `tblvoippolicy`. Now, problem is by mistake i have deleted some records from table.
When I get the data file using following commands.

```
select * from pg_class where relname = 'tblvoippolicy' ; I get the following result

    relname    | relnamespace | reltype | relowner | relam | relfilenode | reltablespace | relpages | reltuples | reltoastrelid | reltoastidxid | relhasindex | relisshared | relkind | relnatts | relchecks | reltriggers | relukeys | relfkeys | relrefs | relhasoids | relhaspkey | relhasrules | relhassubclass | relacl 
---------------+--------------+---------+----------+-------+-------------+---------------+----------+-----------+---------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+---------+----------+-----------+-------------+----------+----------+---------+------------+------------+-------------+----------------+--------
 tblvoippolicy |        17234 |  407227 |      100 |     0 |      407226 |             0 |        0 |         0 |             0 |             0 | t           | f           | r       |        8 |         0 |           0 |        0 |        0 |       0 | t          | t          | f           | f              |
```

Now, when I look that data into data file of database using cat `/var/pgsql/data/base/17230/407226`. I get following result.

```
[root@manage upload]# cat /var/pgsql/data/base/17230/407226
ôu\"(Ô  Ÿà Ÿà¨žð8žàÔÈM ï¡test EC250
@%
ÿ10.106.1.228Q   ï–BEC200_Post_250      EC200
ú%
ú10.106.1.228?   ï”BBS_Service_Pre_250bs_service_1
@&
ú10.106.1.2286   ï’BEC200_Pre_500       EC200
@&
ô10.106.1.228+   ïBEC200_Pre_250       EC200
@&
```

I can not understand the described values and I want to revert back the records which I have deleted from table, how can I get back that records ?

Comment: Have you got a recent backup of the database?

Comment: does this link help?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305961/recover-postgresql-databases-from-raw-physical-files

Comment: @JackDouglas I have not taken any backup.

Comment: @swasheck The problem is I can not understand the data in the data file of postgresql database.

Comment: if you dont have any backups containing those records, you cant revert back them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps.  I would take a backup right away because if vacuum cleans out the deleted row it's gone and you won't have any chance to recover it.

[Recover Deleted Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151632/recoved-deleted-rows-in-postgresql)